# Can't figure out an error with stringWithFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, uialertview, stringwithformat

I'm having a really basic problem with NSString stringWithFormat. I want to take the name that the user enters and display in an alertView: Welcome username.

```
NSString *welcomeMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"Welcome %@", passedData)];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]   //show alert box with option to play or exit
                      initWithTitle: welcomeMessage 
                      message:@"Once you press \"Play\" the timer will start. Good luck!" 
                      delegate:self 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"I want out!" 
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Play",nil];
[alert show];
```

passedData is the username that has been entered. The way I have it at the moment - only the username is being displayed in the title of the alert box, and not the "Welcome" part. I know i'm missing some really basic knowledge here but would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `()` are not needed. Try using that:

```
NSString *welcomeMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@", passedData];
```

instead of

```
NSString *welcomeMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:(@"Welcome %@", passedData)];
```

Hope it helps